# Modelling behaviour of a transformer

Tags: electricity, temperature, electrical-engineering, gas

I'm looking for a physical-mathematical model to describe the behaviour or working point of a [power transformer](https://new.abb.com/products/transformers/power) in dependency on its most critical parameters like oil temperature/heat dissipation, bushing monitoring, gas concentrations, bushing monitoring, voltage loads, resistors, currents and so on.

Overall, I am **not** looking for a regular electronic description or circuit. The aim is to make use of the above mentioned quantities to gain information about the (health) status of the transformer.
Also, I'm more looking for general information, not something very specific from a certain manufacturer for a specific transformer.

I already posted this question here: [Modelling a transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447695/modelling-a-transformer) but it seems it's not adressing the right target group. I hope I do here.

Answer (score 1):

A transformer is electrically modeled as a device which linearly changes the current/voltage relationship of electrical power flowing through it. Real-life transformers contain wire which gets hot when electricity flows through it, so the most important aspect of modeling transformer activity is tracing heat flow out of the transformer core and into the surroundings.

We get the simplest model of a transformer by assuming it has a certain internal volume made out of metal (copper and iron) and a certain surface area for heat transfer. We assume further that the heat generated inside the transformer originates in its center and diffuses out by conduction. Since the conductive medium possesses both heat capacity and conduction, the transformer core will possess a thermal time constant that sets the time scale for the response of the core to the "prompt" heat being generated inside it.

The outer surface of the transformer will possess a certain amount of area and a certain amount of thermal resistance and these two characteristics then determine the rate at which heat will get transferred away into the surroundings for any given temperature of the surface. This is going to yield a second time constant for long-term thermal equilibration of the transformer as a whole and its surroundings.

The critical design parameter is the peak temperature in the inner core of the transformer, because it is that heat which degrades over time the insulation on the wire from which the coils are wound, causing the transformer to fail. The two operating conditions which must be considered are 1) transient power surges, which occur on timescales too fast for the core to dissipate the excess heat to the surroundings, and 2) long-term steady-state core temperature, to which the insulation will be exposed over the useful lifetime of the transformer.

Comment: That's a good starter and you mentioned some very useful aspects. Do you also know a model where one can enter several parameters?

Comment: yes, there is a modeling protocol called *power bond graphing* which can be used to build a model of a transformer from either an electrical or a heat transfer basis- in fact, it allows the electrical and the heat transfer behavior to be linked in the same model. The standard text for power bond graphs is Karnopp & Rosenberg, *System Dynamics: A Unified Approach*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have an eye on it! Do you also know an approach how to model a transformer which is already in the field and operating?

Comment: you'd instrument it with a temperature gauge and a voltage/current monitor, connected to an arduino or raspberry pi board that's wirelessly enabled. I know people who specialize in setting up systems like this.

Comment: but you can hardly measure the temperature inside the transformer(?!)

Comment: you'd need to drill it out and fit it with a probe.

Comment: Sounds totally doable :D ;)

Comment: well, you did ask the question. I'm only trying to help.

Comment: You would drill a hole into an operating transformator?

Comment: no. i would shut it down first.

Comment: this is not possible. I mean, basically it is, but no.
However, once you shut it down, the temperature will change anyway..

Comment: shut it down, install temperature probes, turn it back on, record data.

Comment: I will ask why no transformer manufacturer does that - but I guess there is a reason

Comment: because they already understand the behavior of the transformer as a thermal system and hence do not have to instrument every one of their transformers in the field, having instrumented one or two of them during the initial design testing phase in the laboratory.

Comment: no, that's just not true. I'm working in a company which develops monitoring systems for them, which, in return, is owned by a manufacturer.

Comment: I do not understand this business model and am done here. best of luck.